# Белый расторвый логотип в @media print. Некорректное отображение background в chrome 65

Tags: css, вёрстка, google-chrome

Делаю верстку сайта. Дизайнер отрисовал белый логотип (в темную шапку сайта) в png. Через некоторое время после отправки проекта понадобилось не меняя html сделать приличную страницу для печати. Через `@media print` белый логотип на белой бумаге конечно не виден. Стал пробовать вставить темный логотип через background-image с различными хаками:

```
 @media print{
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
        print-color-adjust: exact !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;   /* Chrome, Safari */
        color-adjust: exact !important;                 /*Firefox*/

        width: 282px;
        height: 170px;
        background-image: url(pic.png) !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        z-index: 99;
    }
```

Все хорошо отображается в firefox, но в chrome поведение стало непредсказуемым. Иногда chrome ткаи отображает логотип на предпросмотре, но чаще нет. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким поведением? Так и не смог решить проблему средствами css. Может кто подсказать? 
На крайний случай подскажите как правильнее вставить картинку для печати через JS. 
Спасибо.

[Update]
Имеется вот такой блок шапки:

```
<header class="main-header">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="hidden">title</h1>
        <div class="main-header__logo">
            <picture>
                <source srcset="img/main-header__logo--d.png" media="(min-width: 1170px)">
                <img src="img/main-header__logo--m.png" alt="Логотип">
            </picture>
        </div>
        <div class="main-header__phone">000 000 000</div>
        <div class="main-header__social">
            <a href="#" class="social-but social-but--fb">fb</a>
            <a href="#" class="social-but social-but--vk">vk</a>
        </div>
        <div class="main-header__request">
            <button class="but">Оставить заявку</button>
        </div>
        <nav class="main-header__main-menu">
            <div class="main-menu">
                <div class="main-menu__cake  main-menu--cake"></div>
                <ul class="main-menu__list  hidden">
                    <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
                    <li class="main-menu--active"><a href="">Каталог</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Сотрудничество</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Вакансии</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

`nav` и все `div`-ы (кроме `main-header__logo` и `main-header__phone`) отключил с помощью `@media print{display: none}`. img в `main-header__logo` также отключил через `display:none`. 
Далее в блок `main-header__logo` указал css-код из первой части моего вопроса (бекграундом вставил черный логотип) и для `main-header__phone` указал через `@media print` выравнивание и цвет.

Также попробовал скрыть полностью `container` и через `before` вставить блок с логотипом:

```
.main-header {
    position: relative;

    height: 244px;

    background: @gray url(../img/header__bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    @media @tablet-size {
        background: @gray url(../img/header__bg-desktop.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
        height: 190px;
    }
    @media @desktop-size {
        height: 323px;
        background: @gray url(../img/header__bg-desktop.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
    box-shadow: inset 0px 141px 300px -48px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);

    @media print {
        box-shadow: none !important;
        background: none !important;
        background-size: auto;

        &::before {
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
            print-color-adjust: exact !important;
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; /* Chrome, Safari */
            color-adjust: exact !important; /*Firefox*/

            width: 282px;
            height: 170px;
            background-image: url(../img/main-header__logo--print.png) !important;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            z-index: 99;
            content: "";
        }
    }

}
.main-header > .container{
    @media print{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Странное поведение в Chrome остается. При тестировании иногда логотип показывается, но чаще нет.

Comment: Нужен живой пример, или больше css, тут не понятно как и где вы подменяете логотип

Comment: Постарался расписать в первом сообщении поподробнее. Не уверен, что это поможет.